# how can I make a copy of the SFRestRequest block?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfrestrequest

I need to know how I can make a copy of the SFRestRequest block in my iOS app built with the Salesforce Mobile SDK 2.0 so that I can not only call once out to salesforce with a SOQL query from one of my implementation files but also make another call out using the second block and then return the message into the same implementation file to be handled (and ultimately assign the JSON into an array of dictionaries). 
I have previously asked a similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18241/how-to-return-the-report-results-from-a-soql-query-using-the-rest-api-in-salesfo) but having spent much time working on a suggested solution I have identified the knowledge gap now which is this question. If I can get this solution I will be then able to populate two arrays with the results of two soil queries from the one implementation file.

Answer (score 4):

You may now replace **"SFRestAPI.h"** with  **"SFRestAPI+Blocks.h"** to call request with block syntax in the Salesforce Mobile SDK:

```
NSDictionary *deleteParams = @{
                                  @"sObjectId":[self.sfdcData objectForKey:@"Id"]
                                  };

SFRestRequest *request = [SFRestRequest requestWithMethod:SFRestMethodDELETE path:@"" queryParams:deleteParams];
    request.endpoint = @"/services/apexrest/WebService";
    //            [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
    [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] sendRESTRequest:request failBlock:nil completeBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseData) {


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", responseData);
            if ([responseData objectForKey:@"isDeleted"])
            {

                [self.resultLabel setText:@"Deleted!"];

            }
        });
    }];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I contributed some [block methods](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/native/SalesforceNativeSDK/SalesforceNativeSDK/Classes/SFRestAPI%2BBlocks.h) to the iOS SDK that makes this very easy.

You might like to read up on Objective-C blocks. You need to be wary about retain cycles in cases where the blocks are copied, as they are in `SFRestAPI`'s blocks category.

You could do something like this:

```
SFRestFailBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed because of %@", error);
};

SFRestDictionaryResponseBlock successBlock = ^(NSDictionary *dict) {
    NSLog(@"Got some records: %@", dict);
};

// A query!
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] performSOQLQuery:@"select id from Account limit 10"
                                   failBlock:failureBlock
                               completeBlock:successBlock];

// Another query!
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] performSOQLQuery:@"select id from Contact limit 10"
                                   failBlock:failureBlock
                               completeBlock:successBlock];
```